# jQuery: How do I reference the @Html.TextBoxFor data in the $('??') of the script?

Tags: jquery-ui, razor, datepicker

I am trying to reference the textboxfor data in the Script above, any ideas please?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('??').datepicker();       
    });
</script>

<div class="editor-label">&nbsp;&nbsp;
    Date:
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RTDATE)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</div>
```

Comment: If you are ever unsure of what ID something has, you can always use Chrome or Firefox and inspect the code. It will show you there.

Answer (score 1):

`@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RTDATE)` will render an input element with the id and name of `RTDATE`.

Using jQuery you can get a handle on it using:

```
$("#RTDATE").datepicker();
```

Answer (score 0):

By default asp.net mvc will generate an input with the same name as your model property.
So in your case above you can do

```
$("#RTDATE").datepicker();
```

[Here's](http://httputility.com/various/razorhelperscheatsheet.html) a quick (although not perfectly formatted) list of the helpers and what they output in html in the default cases.